# Less Than and Equal to (<=) and Greater Than and Equal To (>=) abnormality

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, web-applications

I have a stored procedure for getting the information of an Employee which is automatically filtered by a select element in HTML. The main purpose of this stored procedure is to get all the information of Employee, after that If the Selected Month and Year was change and equal to the Employee Resignation, That Employee will be on the list.

e.g.: `Employee Name` `Resigned-Date`

```
    Alexis Villar  2018/03/07
```

Then if the selected month on the select element is `May` which is `5` when you convert it onto a number and if the year is equal to `2018` then it must be hidden. but in my case, the employee is shown on the list. So now, this is my Stored Procedure.

Code:

```
BEGIN
SELECT  empID, badgenum, first_name, ISNULL(c.groupShortName,'') groupName, 
ISNULL(b.statDesc, '') statDesc,  ISNULL(email,'') email, 
ISNULL(contact_no,'') contact_no, a.resigned_date
FROM userinfo a
LEFT JOIN tblEmpStatus b on a.employment_status = b.statID
LEFT JOIN tblGroup c on a.groupNo = c.groupID
where a.employment_status IN (0,1) OR (a.employment_status = 2 and 
MONTH(a.resigned_date) <= 4  and year(a.resigned_date) <= 2017)
ORDER BY first_name ASC
END
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Regards,

Comment: When you convert `may` into number it should be `5` not `4` because `4` is `april`

Comment: are you after of who resigned on or before April 2017?

Comment: Sorry, My Bad Sir.

Comment: If the Selected date Has an equal to a Resigned Employee, Then it must be shown on the list. but if not. it must be hidden. That's the main Logic of this Procedure Sir.

Comment: try doing it in `sqlfiddle.com` or `rextester.com` and muck up your schema, data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be with "employment_status" column..could you be more elaborate on what status 0 to 2 mean..or could you check the status values of the returned rows which are not supposed to be there..this should provide a  fix